# Using polymer paper-button with button_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymer-1.0

I am trying to use polymer 1.0 in rails 4 with the polymer-rails and polymer-elements-rails gems. How do I use the button_to under the  tags?

```
<paper-button raised>
<%= button_to "About", "pages/about", :method => :get %>
About</paper-button>
```

This actually creates two buttons. The button with button_to is functional.

Is some other element is required for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way because your Rails helper method is generating a standard HTML Button tag (probably with a wrapping Form element), and then it's being inserted.

In Polymer, you're expected to use the on-click attribute on the element to call a method in the containing element.

`<paper-button on-click="buttonClicked>` for example.

This makes using the standard Rails helper methods unusable, and you'll have to find another way to handle the click event, or indeed make your own custom Polymer element and a matching Rails helper.

Comment: Just tried to answer this in the iOS app and for some reason my HTML is missing. Sorry

Comment: Thanks for the explaination @stef. Please try to add HTML example later.

Comment: If polymer forces to use onclick attribute, then isn't it a loss of rails functionality. The simplicity of rails is no more

Comment: You can still use Rails helpers alongside Polymer elements, but Paper elements are sufficiently complex that you'd be better off looking at Iron ones and seeing if you get anywhere.